# EF: Map base class property with fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have problem with inheritance code first.
I have base class which look like this:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string UserCreatedId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
    public string UserModifiedId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserState UserCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual UserState UserModified { get; set; }
}
```

and i have Inherited it and this give me a additional column with  name UserCreated_userStateId and UserModified_UserStateId. So I try fluent API like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>().HasOptional(x => x.UserCreated).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.UserCreatedId);
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>().HasOptional(X => X.UserModified).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.UserModifiedId);
```

But this give me error: "One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

BaseEntity: : EntityType 'BaseEntity' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
BaseEntities: EntityType: EntitySet 'BaseEntities' is based on type 'BaseEntity' that has no keys defined." How to avoid define the key and only change mapping of property? I have key in derived class.

Comment: So you want to define individual keys for each derived class and use "table per concrete class" strategy? Then you should configure the base class properties on derived class entities.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are not using **EF inheritance**, but simple C# class inheritance?

Comment: Yes, but i have to many derived class to configure it all one by one. This will be produce me many copy paste code and i dont want it. Its any better solution? Yes i have C# class inheritance i try get clean model and get everything in fluent API.

Comment: Normally this would not require any configuration. If EF creates additional columns, there must be a type mismatch - what is the **type** of PK property of the `UserState` class?

Comment: The Type of PK is string but i need to told EF which string property need to be FK of which userState as you can see i have two of them. Normally EF will take it from class name when i named FK like UserStateId.

Comment: Believe me or not, but it correctly associates `UserCreatedId` with `UserCreated` and `UserModifiedId` with `UserModified`. If you are not sure, the easiest is to put `ForeignKey` attributes, configuring via fluent API in such scenario is quite problematic (if possible at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your base class configuration in a generic method and call it for each concrete entity type.

```
static void ConfigureBaseEntity<TDerived>(EntityTypeConfiguration<TDerived> entityTypeConfiguration) where TDerived : BaseEntity
{
    // your base class configuration
    entityTypeConfiguration.HasOptional(x => x.UserCreated).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.UserCreatedId);
    entityTypeConfiguration.HasOptional(X => X.UserModified).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.UserModifiedId);
}
```

Call for each concrete entity type

```
public class DerivedEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

//...
ConfigureBaseEntity(modelBuilder.Entity<DerivedEntity>());
```

**Edit**

Maybe the `Types` configuration is enough for your purpose.

```
modelBuilder.Types<BaseEntity>().Configure(entityTypeConfiguration => /* configure using entityTypeConfiguration  */);
```

Otherwise, as commented, you may need reflection. For example, lets say all your derived classes are in the same assembly as the `BaseEntity` class and the `ConfigureBaseEntity` method from above is in class `BaseEntityConfiguration`.

```
var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");
var configurationMethod = typeof(BaseEntityConfiguration).GetMethod("ConfigureBaseEntity");
foreach (Type t in typeof(BaseEntity).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseEntity))))
{
    var configurator = entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[0]);
    configurationMethod.MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(null, new object[1] { configurator });
}
```

However, if it was my code, I'd prefer to write one line of code per entity class instead of going for the dynamic discovery.

Comment: This answer produce so many copy paste code if i have many DerivedEntity, maybe is some cleaner way to do that?

Comment: @CrazyBaran Feel free to use things like reflection or MEF in order to gather a derived class collection and create a reflection based version of my code if a one-liner per concrete class is to much for your case.

Comment: Ok, first approach works and i think i will stay with it for now. +1